# Prefab Instantiates into scene, but when I store a reference to the instance it's null

Tags: c#, unity, gameobject

I am instantiating and parenting two objects - the first is a Unity primitive and the second is a prefab cube (literally nothing but a cube made into a prefab). The direct instantiation of the primitive works great, but when I try to instantiate the prefab I get ***NullReferenceException:Object reference not set to an instance of an object***

Below is my script:

```
    Vector3 myPosition = new Vector3 (x, Rotator_Prefab.transform.position.y , z);
    GameObject ball = GameObject.CreatePrimitive (PrimitiveType.Sphere);
    ball.transform.parent = gameObject.transform; // no problems and gameObject.name gives me the right parent


    GameObject prefab = Instantiate (Rotator_Prefab, myPosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    prefab.transform.parent = gameObject.transform; // this gives me an error
```

The error is coming from the prefab still being null after being instantiated. Still it shows up in the scene. Would anyone have any ideas ? 
- Thank you!

Update: Where the prefab is coming from

[image]

Comment: I am positive the parent isn't null, because the primitive object finds it and also when I print(gameObject.name) it gives me the right parent... The parent is there, but the prefab doesn't acknowledge it

Comment: You are instantiating the root node here.  There is no parent, it would be impossible for the "prefab" object to have a parent here.  Not sure why you would assume otherwise.

Comment: Hi Jon, I don't think I understand what you mean. My script has a public Gameobject variable where I drag&drop the prefab. The script itself is attached to a Gameobject (i.e the intended parent) - I instantiate the prefab and the primitive from the same place in the script ..

Comment: That instantiated "prefab" object in your code above, would not have a parent, as you just instantiated it and it isn't associated with another gameObject at that point.  It doesn't matter where you instantiate it from.

Comment: Okay, so it gets instantiated at the top level in the hierarchy. But is it not possible to assign it to the parent of the script after being instantiated? I tried with gameObject.transform and then GameObject.Find('parentName').transform and still the same error.

Comment: transform.parent = prefab.transform;

Comment: Put a breakpoint, run your code in a debugger, and check what object is null!

Comment: Alexandre you are right! - Its the prefab that is null! (but why??)

Comment: @Jon, the absence of a parent to the new spawned prefab would not cause an error here, because we're *assigning to* the parent field, not trying to access any members of a purported parent object. **BonnieB**, can you show us where you declare & assign the `Rotator_Prefab` variable? If it's not of type `GameObject` then `Instantiate` won't return a `GameObject` and the `as GameObject` will quietly replace whatever valid thing it did return with `null`. Then accessing `prefab.transform` is like asking for `null.transform`. Instantiate works on all kinds of types and returns the type you put in.

Comment: Why don't you take over.  I'm done here.

Comment: maybe because you don't load it properly. I assume rotator prefab is a gameobject. you first need to load your asset into it. you can do `Rotator_Prefab = Resources.Load<Gameobject>(*your prefab path*);`
if you drag n dropped your prefab in the script the engin will ignore it. if you want to drag n drop you to do it in you script component in the hierarchy

Comment: DMGregory, @Leggy7: You guys are really helpful and on to something - I am indeed just dropping the prefab in the script (see updated question). I just tried with ***Rotator_Prefab = Resources.Load<Gameobject>("Prefab/Capsule")*** but am getting ***error CS0029: Cannot convert type "UnityEngine.GameObject" to 'UnityEngine.Transform'*** ......

Comment: In your script the Rotator_prefab public field should be of type GameObject, not Transform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, keeping the code from the question and changing the public field of the Prefab to type ***GameObject*** (not Transform) did the trick.

(I did not need to use Resources.Load("*PATH*");)

I hope this saves someone some time

Comment: If you want more context for why this happened, it's the use of `as GameObject` after the `Instantiate` - the type of the object you pass to `Instantiate` is the type you'll get back (useful if you want to use a specific type for your prefab field, like Rigidbody if it needs physics, and get back a reference to the Rigidbody on the spawned instance without a separate `GetComponent` step). Since your prefab was a `Transform`, the `as GameObject` replaced the return value with null. This would also work: `Transform instance = (Transform)Instantiate(prefabThatIsATransform); instance.parent = ...`

Answer (score 1):

For what I've seen in the comments your prefab is null because there is nothing assigned at runtime.

Drag n dropping stuff in the inspector of your script is ignored by the engine at scene load. Once your script is assigned as component to a gameObject in your hiearchy then public slots will appear and you should do there your drag n drop.

Otherwise you can dynamically load via script doing

```
Rotator_Prefab = Resources.Load<Gameobject>(*your prefab path*);
```

**After you edit** I should specify that your variable must be of type GameObject to instantiate it correctly.

Comment: I think we should clarify that it only needs to be a `GameObject` because the code around the `Instantiate()` is expecting a `GameObject` out in this particular example. `Instantiate()` works with any type derived from `UnityEngine.Object` (including `Component`s & `Monobehaviour`s, `Material`s, etc), so it's not only `GameObjects` that can be correctly instantiated as a general rule.